# WCF FaultException naming conflict

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have 2 WCF services (different projects) sharing  a class library with a MyExceptions defined.

Both services uses:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
void op();
```

When I add both references in the client project I get:

> Type namespace.MyException already defines a member called MyException
>   with the same parameter types.

Basically the classes has the same name so the constructor is defined twice.
Any Idea of how to change the Exception namespace?

Please note that:

- I am using svcutils
- the namespace option doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused here. What do you mean "the namespace option doesn't work"? Have you tried using `[FaultContract(typeof(some.namespace.MyException))]`? (I'm assuming the two versions of `MyException` have differing namespaces..?)

Comment: If i use svcutil /namespace:*,MyNs http://myUrl I get Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the proxy using [`svcutil /reference:SharedLibrary.dll`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/10/09/reusing-types-in-referenced-assemblies-with-svcutil-s-r-switch.aspx). This way `svcutil` won't generate classes that it finds in the `SharedLibrary.dll`, so the client uses the class definitions from the assembly.

Don't forget to add a reference to the DLL in the client project, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and will let you know

Answer (score 1):

Besides the namespace suggestion what can be done is to edit the proxy code generated by SVCUTIL and remove the duplicate code for the MyException class.

The steps:
1. Create a proxy file for Service1. 
2. Create a proxy file for Service2.
3. Add the proxies to the client.
4. Compile and it gives error for having MyException already being declared.
5. Edit either one of the proxies and remove the MyException class code.

Comment: That's what I am doing now. Thanks for the answer.